# call a func in NSWindowController from custom class for an NSView

Tags: macos, swift2

I have a "sheet" as `NSWindowController` in Swift, for OS X.  I placed an `NSView` on the sheet, with a custom controller in a class called `CustomView`. Everything I do on the sheet and in the custom view controller works fine.

```
class MySheet: NSWindowController {

//...

}

class CustomView: NSView {

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {

        super.drawRect(dirtyRect) {

        // Draw some things...

        }
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        // Change text on a label (or whatever) in MySheet()
    }
}
```

Now I need to respond to user input in the `CustomView`, specifically, a mouse click on the view, and modify a label (or other control) back in MySheet().  This has to be very simple, but I don't know how to do it.  The biggest stumbling block I have is that I don't have an instance of MySheet(); it is hidden in the way the system works.  I can call back to a static func in MySheet(), but that won't let me change a label or other control through an @IBOutlet.

I know the above is a most likely a naive question, but would appreciate any help toward a solution.

Comment: I am confused. Is there an instance of CustomView in the window controlled by MySheet? And is the content view of the window loaded from a storyboard or xib?

Answer (score 0):

Of course (!), this problem is supposed to be solved using a delegate, and when it is set up correctly it works fine.  So I have like this:

```
protocol ClickableCurves {
    func clickedOnCurve(index: Int)
}

class MySheet: NSWindowController, ClickableCurves {

    private let lineColorCount = 16

    func clickedOnCurve(index: Int) {
        Swift.print("came back as \(index)")
    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        (curveView as! DefaultCurveAttrView).delegate = self
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var curveView: NSView!
}    

class DefaultCurveAttrView: NSView {

    var delegate: ClickableCurves? = nil

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {

        let frameRelWindow = self.convertRect(bounds, toView: nil)

        let x = theEvent.locationInWindow.x - frameRelWindow.origin.x
        let y = theEvent.locationInWindow.y - frameRelWindow.origin.y

        let xm = bounds.width / 10
        let dy = bounds.height / CGFloat(lineColorCount + 1)

        var yc: CGFloat = dy / 2

        if x >= xm && x <= 9 * xm {
            for i in 1 ... lineColorCount {

                yc += dy

                if yc > y || i == lineColorCount {
                    if delegate != nil {
                        delegate!.clickedOnCurve(i - 1)
                    }

                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```